# SQL Access Queries about Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Consider table:

```
STUDENT (
    School_ID char(3), 
    St_LastName char(15), 
    St_FirstName char(15), 
    St_DOB char(15), 
    St_SS# char(15), 
    St_Address char(15),
    St_City char(15), 
    St_State char(2),
    st_Zip char(5), 
    st_phone char(15)
);
```

1.Display students that were born after August 01, 1989.

Your answer should be specific for Microsoft-Access......

Comment: Are you playing quiz here?

Comment: @Ken Clark..no..i m not getting how to do it

Comment: What is the data type of the field St_DOB? If it's anything other than date, then you will have to convert it first. What I usually do is make a new column with data type date and `UPDATE` it with the contents of the original date. After that, the query becomes easier (`SELECT * FROM` table `WHERE` field > date)

Comment: Welcome to SO. [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).